# How to force the view of a website to start at the bottom of a page (so that users must scroll up)

Tags: javascript, css, scroll, footer

I'd like to build a novelty beanstalk-themed website where content is built from the bottom up rather than the top down. Imagine a page that is 10,000px tall. Is there a way to:

1. Stack content, starting with a div on the bottom of a page, with each additionally-added div stacked on top of its predecessor?
2. Force the user's view such that upon visiting a page, they start at the bottom and must scroll up to access additional content?

I realize this does not present an intuitive user experience, so please ignore why I want to do this, and focus on the technicalities of how to do it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To scroll to the bottom, try the following:

```
x = 0;  //horizontal coord
y = document.height; //vertical coord
window.scroll(x,y);
```

To build up your content in reverse order, try the jQuery [prepend](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/) function.

Comment: **UPDATE**: This answer is deprecated since Gecko 6.0 and the appropiate references. Use instead `document.body.clientHeight`. More info [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.height#Alternatives).